# How can I copy all of the files using a single command in bash script

Tags: bash

The code below helps me to copy files from test1 folder to test2 folder but I dnot need to make test2 folder each time and dont want for leap for each time, I need to copy all of the mentioned files in the code with single command, IS this possible?

```
for file in /Path/test1/*mdp ; do
    mkdir -p /Path/test2/"$name"
    cp "$file" "/Path/test2/$name"
done

for file in /Path/test1/*gro ; do
    mkdir -p /Path/test2/"$name"
    cp "$file" "/Path/test2/$name"
done

for file in /Path/test1/*top ; do
    mkdir -p /Path/test2/"$name"
    cp "$file" "/Path/test2/$name"
done

for file in /Path/test1/*nvt1.cpt ; do
    mkdir -p /Path/test2/"$name"
    cp "$file" "/Path/test2/$name"
done
```

Comment: What is `$name` in this case? The code would not need it to be mkdir-ed repeatedly unless it is changing, but there is no indication that it changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
newpath="/Path/test2/$name"
mkdir -p "$newpath"

cp /Path/test1/*{mdp,grp,top,nvt1,cpt} "$newpath"
```

Comment: newpath="${PWD/1/2}" (kidding)

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop can take multiple patterns; the expansion of each is combined into a single list which the loop iterates over. The `mkdir` command can be moved outside the loop, since it doesn't depend on the value of `file`.

```
mkdir -p /Path/test2/"$name"
for file in /Path/test1/*mdp /Path/test1/*gro /Path/test1/*top /Path/test1/*nvt1.cpt ; do
    cp "$file" "/Path/test2/$name"
done
```

However, [anubhava's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33370435/1126841) is better since it only runs `cp` once, instead of once per file. The braces are a shortcut for the longer, but standard

```
cp /Path/test1/*mdp /Path/test1/*grp /Path/test1/*top /Path/test1/*nvt1 /Path/test1/*cpt "$newpath"
```